# Parsing and removing table entries from HTML with Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I currently have a downloaded HTML page that is 300MB in size. It cannot be opened right now. The file creates a multiple  entries with data relating to files within the table. A sample is below:

```
<div class="item">
      <h2>install.log</h2> 

<table>
        <col width="1*"/>
        <col width="2*"/>
        <tbody>


          <tr>
            <th>Local Copy:</th>
            <td>
              <a href="./Items/Test/Test/Test.L01/Sideways%123/D/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/install.log">install</a>
            </td>
          </tr>



          <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td>
                                    install.log
                            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Path Name:</th>
            <td>
                                    /Test/Test/Test.L01/Sideways123/D/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox
                            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>GUID:</th>
            <td>
                                    <tt>efaa12b1-e4b0-4ed8-9d14-b2dbf8d707fe</tt>
                            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Item Date:</th>
            <td>
                                    Wednesday, 25 March 2009 15:14:39 o'clock GMT
                            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>File Created:</th>
            <td>
                                    Wednesday, 25 March 2009 15:14:36 o'clock GMT
                            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>File Modified:</th>
            <td>
                                    Wednesday, 25 March 2009 15:14:39 o'clock GMT
                            </td>
          </tr>



        </tbody>
      </table>

 </div>
```

What I'm looking to do is strip out some of the table entries so that I can open the file in a browser and a lot of the entries aren't relevant. 
In the example above, the section commences with `<h2></h2>` with an entry for the file inclusive of the file extension. I want to write a python script which will basically allow me to list a number of file extensions (ie .log, .txt etc.) and I'd then like to edit the HTML page and only include those entries that contain those file extensions and if this isn't the case, remove the table entry and all the associated data for that table entry. So in the code above, the whole of this data would be stripped out from the HTML if I were to solely look for files with .xls and .jpg for example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: beautifulsoup ? get all td's?